# Will php being out of memory caused by increasing memory leak?

Tags: php

I am really confused about php memory management.

Will php being out of memory caused by increasing memory leak of php itself ?

If not, and with zend_gc = On.
Why can we face out of memory situations when running phpunit?

Comment: have you tried to increase memory_limit in php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

> Hey just changed the following things :

change `php.ini` to...

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

and add to `httpd.conf`

```
RLimitMEM 1073741824 2147483648
```

and **restart apache** & **its Removed the error.**